# How can I connect a CPVC pipe to a chrome fitting for a toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

So I ran some CPVC pipe to a new toilet.  I'm curious about the last hook up to the toilet.  I got a threaded female chrome to thread on a male cpvc fitting, but it seems like the threads won't fit snug.  Both are 1/2".  Any ideas on how I should hook up the part going out of the wall to the toilet?  I have a hose that should fit the chrome shutoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metal stop valve attached to a CPVC pipe thread adapter is the correct transition. I agree the plastic male PT adapters seem to thread too far into equivalent female fittings, the resulting snugness seems unsatisfactory. Despite that, I've never had one leak. At least it's exposed and available for inspection and it's easy to disassemble for correction.

Comment: Looks like I just needed to use a wrench and get some more twists / french on it.  I wish I could accept both answers though.

Answer (score 2):

Sharkbite is a brand of product that will do what you ask. Very simple to use, just push it on after you cut the pipe clean and square with no distortion (always follow the instructions with the product)

[image]

It will give a tidy look when installed.